# How to get aggregation in org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.FacetedPage

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, facet

I have to perform search with aggregation in elastic search. Since facets will be removed in near future, I can not use facets.

Of course I am encouraged to use Aggregation.

Below code gives me desired output :

Aggregations aggregations = elasticsearchTemplate.query(searchQuery, new ResultsExtractor() {
         @Override
         public Aggregations extract(SearchResponse response) {
         return response.getAggregations();

But the problem is that it becomes the second query apart from my elastic search query which makes it very slower.

I am using spring data elastic search api to perform search :

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository {

```
/**
 * This method fetches all customer objects.
 *
 */
@Override
Iterable<Customer> search(QueryBuilder query);
```

}

The query builder I am passing to elasticsearch repository contains the Annotation query by using api addAggregation();

The question is  : how to get the Aggregation from this FacetedPage ?

Request help.

Answer (score -3):

refer the tutorial.  about the spring aggregation topic.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html

Comment: buddy, your link is about mongodb :(